# GmailApp.sendEmail is sending a copy of the sent email to my inbox

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

GmailApp.sendEmail is sending a copy of emails sent via Google App Script

I have set up a simple family birthday reminder that sends an email to family members to remind them its someone's birthday soon.

Its working fine, but what im seeing is that its sending a copy of the sent emails to my inbox - which is somewhat annoying as we have 14 kids and 10 emails on the list so I end up getting quite a few copies in my inbox.

Ive read here on stackoverflow that using MailApp.sendEmail is usually the culprit and you should use Gmail.App.sendEmail instead, but I am using Gmail.App.sendEmail so im unsure what to do next.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I use `GmailApp.sendEmail` for various things and have never had this issue, so I suspect that this has something to do with a Gmail setting as opposed to some issue with code. Maybe something here might help you: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/4950575/i-do-not-want-sent-mail-in-my-inbox?hl=en (I see you are changing the `from` alias, so maybe that's causing it to get caught by a filter or something).

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I did indeed have a filter on my own email address, never send to spam always send to inbox.

Ive cleared it so hopefully this might sort it.

Comment: Awesome, feel free to submit that as an answer to your own question so it's easier for others to find if they stumble upon the same issue.